# How to manipulate directories using Python

Tags: python, git

I'm using the following lump of code to manage a 9.4gb dataset.  I had to divide the dataset into multiple github repositories to be able to do this. I've explained what each block of code does.

```
git_repo_tags = ['AB', 'C', 'DEF', 'G', 'HILMNO', 'PR', 'STW', 'X']
counter = 1

# Cloning the github repositories
print('Beginning cloning...')
for repo in git_repo_tags:
  git.Git('.').clone('git://github.com/utility-repos/' + repo)
  print('-\nCloning ' + repo)

  #Removing the .git folder from each repo
  shutil.rmtree(repo + '/.git')
  print('--Removing the .git folder ' + str(counter) + '/8')
  counter += 1

# Creating the Food-101/images directory and subdirectory if it doesn't already exist
if not os.path.exists('Food-101/images'):
    os.makedirs('Food-101/images')
    print('Created the Food-101/images')

    # Going through the repo X and moving everything a branch up
    for i in os.listdir('X'):
      shutil.move(os.path.join('X', i), 'Food-101')
      print('Moved important files to an upper branch')

    # Going through the other repos and moving everything to Food-101/images
    for directory in git_repo_tags:
      for subdirectory in os.listdir(directory):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(directory, subdirectory), 'Food-101/images')
        print('Moving ' + subdirectory + ' to Food-101/images')


#After the above code is complete, moves all test images to the Food-101/test folder and renames them
print('\n-Beginning to separate the test dataset...')
if not os.path.exists('Food-101/test'):
    os.makedirs('Food-101/test')

with open('Food-101/meta/test.txt') as test_file:
  for line in test_file:
    name_of_folder = line.split('/')[0]
    name_of_file = line.split('/')[1].rstrip()
    Path('Food-101/images/' + name_of_folder + '/' + name_of_file + '.jpg').rename('Food-101/test/' + name_of_folder + '_' + name_of_file + '.jpg')
    print('--Moved Food-101/images/' + name_of_folder + '/' + name_of_file + '.jpg to Food-101/test/')

# Moves all training images to the Food-101/images directory and renames them
print('\n-Beginning to separate the training dataset...')
with open('Food-101/meta/train.txt') as train_file:

  for line in train_file:
    name_of_folder = line.split('/')[0]
    name_of_file = line.split('/')[1].rstrip()
    Path('Food-101/images/' + name_of_folder + '/' + name_of_file + '.jpg').rename('Food-101/images/' + name_of_folder + '_' + name_of_file + '.jpg')
    print('--Moved Food-101/images/' + name_of_folder + '/' + name_of_file + '.jpg to Food-101/train/')

# Removes empty directories inside Food-101/images
with open('Food-101/meta/train.txt') as train_file:
  for folder in train_file:
    name_of_folder = folder.split('/')[0]
    if os.path.exists('Food-101/images/' + name_of_folder):
      shutil.rmtree('Food-101/images/' + name_of_folder)

# Removes empty directories 
for dirs in git_repo_tags:
  shutil.rmtree(dirs)
```

This code works but its a mess and I have too many repeats.  What is a good way to clean this up?

Answer (score 3):

### Enumerate

```
counter = 1
for repo in git_repo_tags:
  # ...
  print('--Removing the .git folder ' + str(counter) + '/8')
  counter += 1
```

should be using `enumerate`:

```
for counter, repo in enumerate(git_repo_tags, start=1):
```

### String interpolation

```
print('--Removing the .git folder ' + str(counter) + '/8')
```

can be

```
print(f'--Removing the .git folder {counter}/{len(git_repo_tags)}')
```

The 8 should not be hard-coded.

### Pathlib

For basically every one of your directory and file names, and many of your file operations (`rmtree` being an exception), you should consider using `pathlib.Path`. For instance, this:

```
if not os.path.exists('Food-101/images'):
    os.makedirs('Food-101/images')
    print('Created the Food-101/images')
```

can be

```
image_path = Path('Food-101/images')
if not image_path.exists():
    image_path.mkdir(parents=True)
    print(f'Created {image_path}')
```

### Path parsing

Rather than this:

```
name_of_folder = line.split('/')[0]
name_of_file = line.split('/')[1].rstrip()
```

consider at least unpacking it, i.e.

```
folder_name, file_name = line.rsplit('/', 1)
```

But it's better to again use `pathlib`:

```
line_path = Path(line)
folder_name = line_path.parent
file_name = line_path.name
```

### Functions

Move logically-related chunks of code to subroutines for better legibility, maintainability, modularity, testability, etc.

### Indentation

Use four spaces, which is more standard. You do this in some places but not others.